# HTML elements misaligned with page zoom

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I have a navigation bar with drop down menus created with UL elements. Currently, the drop down table shifts when the web page is zoomed in or out. How do I style the CSS so that the drop down menus will stay aligned?

```
<ul id="links">
  <li>First link</li>
  <li>Second link
    <ul id="dropdown1">
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Third link</li>
  <li>Fourth link
    <ul id="dropdown2">
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
      <li>Drop down item 1</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VDpbb/).

Comment: Browser zoom is there for a convenience. It was never designed to maintain layouts at different zoom levels. There is no real use-case for tweaking your CSS to make it work at every zoom-level on every browser.

Comment: @LcSalazar Uploaded the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/VDpbb/

Comment: As @Diodeus said, the browser's zoom function is merely for convenience and accessibility purposes.  As far as I know, there is no way to maintain your layout perfectly, when zooming.